# Water is dripping on gas water heater burner?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I had gone on vacation and left water heater off. After 3 weeks I turned it on and trying to bring it back on.
I saw when burner went ON, the water is dripping every second and have a sizzling sound. After 10 seconds I put it back in off.
Is this because of condensation?
How would I check if water is leaking ?

Also I see the flag light blinking Two times in every 3 seconds when it was ON.

Comment: How old is the heater?

Comment: As for what the light means, you've not bothered to tell us the make and model of your heater, so no *bleeping* idea what that means. [Edit] to provide more details...

Comment: It’s probably 9-10!year old . It’s Bradford white brand. Model RG30T6N

Comment: You slipped a digit, evidently. RG130T6N exists. And two **quick** flashes in 3 seconds means the thermostat is calling for heat, while two flashes in 3 seconds means weak pilot light. http://s3.supplyhouse.com/product_files/BradfordWhite-RG130T6N-User-Guide.pdf

Comment: So it means it’s operating normally. But as I mentioned below as well  why the pilot light goes off automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ran it for all of 10 seconds?

Yes, it's almost certainly condensation. You have a tank full of cold water and a flame with water as a significant component of the combustion products in the hot gas exhaust.

If water was **not** dripping **before** you lit the burner, it's most probably not a leak. Likewise if water is not dripping (*or not at the same rate; depending how much flue is dripping back here, it could take a while to dry out*) an hour after you shut it off.

Comment: So how should i processed now after I waited for 8 hours?

Comment: Is it still dripping? If not, turn it on and let it burn (and drip, until it doesn't drip) until the water is hot.

Comment: Why pilot light goes out after 10-15 seconds ?

Comment: Are you following the procedure in the manual for lighting the pilot? You once again are not providing enough detail, and possibly asking a whole new question, (which should not be done as a comment) in a comment that does not make it clear if you are having trouble lighting the pilot, or if the main flame is lighting and the pilot is then going out.